# FitNesse Error: Could not find fixture

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to build few tests using the FitNesse framework in Java. For some reason, I get an error "Could not find fixture: script" when I try to use the script table.
I am sure I have all the libraries configured in my classpath.

Searching in Google doesn't have much information.

Any pointers would be very helpful

Thanks,
Javid

Comment: Need more info: FitNesse test page, Java source

Answer (score 4):

Script table must start with "Script" as keyword followed by Class name.  Before that you need to define the test as Slim

Syntax: !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

Answer (score 2):

hope you have indicated the test system to use is Slim and make sure you have fitnesse.jar in the path. Example

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path fitnesse.jar
```

http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.DebugingFixtureCode could help debug

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my decision table in FitNesse 20130530 standalone. All I had to fix it is this:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
```

FitNesse JAR is prepended to the ClassPath by FitNesse.